# Why does my CTE join update so much slower than my Table variable join?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, table-variable

I've seen a couple of similar threads, but they all seem to be about massive databases. I've created a dummy database to demonstrate the issue after seeing this crop up in a small live database this morning.

The basis for this data is as follows: a company keeps track of stock portfolios for its 100 clients. Each of 1000 stocks has a daily record that lists the four investors that own it, along with their percentage. Unfortunately, it has a glitch that allows for an owner to show up multiple times. The procedure parses the data and separates the records out so there are 4 records for each stock on each day, and it will then add up the portfolio total for each owner. However, because there are multiple records, that can overstate the value for that owner. So a flag is being inserted to identify any of these duplicates. Later in the code, the value of each line is multiplied by that flag, which is 0 for a duplicate and 1 if not.

I have five methods of updating that flag. I start with 0, which is just to use a CTE with a SELECT statement as a baseline; it takes about 0.07 seconds. 1 uses that CTE with a JOIN to update the table and takes about 48 seconds. 2 uses a nested select statement instead of the CTE and takes about 48 seconds. 3 dumps that CTE to a table variable and and joins to that and takes about 0.13 seconds. 4 I had thought would be the least efficient because it uses a counter loop and updates one row at a time, but it only took 0.17 seconds. 5 uses a CASE statement to update all rows, joined to a CTE, and takes about 48 seconds.

```
DECLARE @OwnRec TABLE (
      StockID           INT
    , TradeDate         DATE
    , Shares            DECIMAL(4,0)
    , Price             DECIMAL(4,2)
    , Owner1            INT
    , Owner1Pct         DECIMAL(3,2)
    , Owner2            INT
    , Owner2Pct         DECIMAL(3,2)
    , Owner3            INT
    , Owner3Pct         DECIMAL(3,2)
    , Owner4            INT
    , Owner4Pct         DECIMAL(3,2)
    )

DECLARE @OwnRec2 TABLE (
      RecID             INT IDENTITY
    , StockID           INT
    , TradeDate         DATE
    , Shares            DECIMAL(4,0)
    , Price             DECIMAL(4,2)
    , Owner0            INT
    , Owner0Pct         DECIMAL(3,2)
    , OwnerNum          INT
    , DupeOwner         TINYINT
    )

DECLARE @CullDupe TABLE (
      ID                INT IDENTITY
    , RecID             INT
    )

DECLARE   @Method       INT
        , @Counter1     INT = 0
        , @StartTime    DATETIME

--Populate tables with dummy data
WHILE @Counter1 < 1000
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter1 += 1
        INSERT INTO @OwnRec (
              StockID
            , TradeDate
            , Shares    
            , Price     
            , Owner1    
            , Owner1Pct
            , Owner2    
            , Owner2Pct
            , Owner3    
            , Owner3Pct
            , Owner4    
            , Owner4Pct
            )
        SELECT @Counter1
            , '2016-09-26'
            , ROUND((RAND() * 1000 + 500)/25,0)*25
            , ROUND((RAND() * 30 + 20),2)
            , ROUND((RAND() * 100 + .5),0)
            , CAST(ROUND((RAND() * 5 + .5),0)*.05 AS DECIMAL(3,2))
            , ROUND((RAND() * 100 + .5),0)
            , CAST(ROUND((RAND() * 5 + .5),0)*.05 AS DECIMAL(3,2))
            , ROUND((RAND() * 100 + .5),0)
            , CAST(ROUND((RAND() * 5 + .5),0)*.05 AS DECIMAL(3,2))
            , ROUND((RAND() * 100 + .5),0)
            , CAST(ROUND((RAND() * 5 + .5),0)*.05 AS DECIMAL(3,2))
    END

SET @Counter1 = 0

WHILE @Counter1 < 1000
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter1 += 1
        INSERT INTO @OwnRec (
              StockID
            , TradeDate
            , Shares    
            , Price     
            , Owner1    
            , Owner1Pct
            , Owner2    
            , Owner2Pct
            , Owner3    
            , Owner3Pct
            , Owner4    
            , Owner4Pct
            )
        SELECT @Counter1 + 1000
            , '2016-09-27'
            , Shares
            , ROUND(Price * ROUND(RAND()*10 + .5,0)*.01+.95,2)
            , Owner1    
            , Owner1Pct
            , Owner2    
            , Owner2Pct
            , Owner3    
            , Owner3Pct
            , Owner4    
            , Owner4Pct
            FROM @OwnRec WHERE StockID = @Counter1
    END

UPDATE orx
    SET Owner2Pct = Owner1Pct
        FROM @OwnRec orx
            WHERE Owner1 = Owner2

UPDATE orx
    SET Owner3Pct = Owner1Pct
        FROM @OwnRec orx
            WHERE Owner1 = Owner3

UPDATE orx
    SET Owner4Pct = Owner1Pct
        FROM @OwnRec orx
            WHERE Owner1 = Owner4

UPDATE orx
    SET Owner3Pct = Owner2Pct
        FROM @OwnRec orx
            WHERE Owner2 = Owner3

UPDATE orx
    SET Owner4Pct = Owner2Pct
        FROM @OwnRec orx
            WHERE Owner2 = Owner4

UPDATE orx
    SET Owner4Pct = Owner3Pct
        FROM @OwnRec orx
            WHERE Owner3 = Owner4

INSERT INTO @OwnRec2
    SELECT StockID, TradeDate, Shares, Price, Owner1 AS Owner0, Owner1Pct, 1, 1 AS Owner0Pct
        FROM @OwnRec
    UNION
    SELECT StockID, TradeDate, Shares, Price, Owner2 AS Owner0, Owner2Pct, 2, 1 AS Owner0Pct
        FROM @OwnRec
    UNION
    SELECT StockID, TradeDate, Shares, Price, Owner3 AS Owner0, Owner3Pct, 3, 1 AS Owner0Pct
        FROM @OwnRec
    UNION
    SELECT StockID, TradeDate, Shares, Price, Owner4 AS Owner0, Owner4Pct, 4, 1 AS Owner0Pct
        FROM @OwnRec
--END Populate tables with dummy data

SET @StartTime = GETDATE()

SET @Method = 5 -- Choose which method to test


--CASE 0: Just identify duplicates

IF @Method = 0
    BEGIN
        ; WITH CullDupe
            AS (
                SELECT RecID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StockID, TradeDate, Owner0 ORDER BY OwnerNum) AS rn
                    FROM @OwnRec2
                )
        SELECT * FROM CullDupe WHERE rn > 1
    END


--CASE 1: Update on JOIN to CTE

IF @Method = 1
    BEGIN
        ; WITH CullDupe
            AS (
                SELECT RecID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StockID, TradeDate, Owner0 ORDER BY OwnerNum) AS rn
                    FROM @OwnRec2
                )
        UPDATE OR2
            SET DupeOwner = 0
                FROM @OwnRec2 OR2
                    JOIN CullDupe cd
                        ON OR2.RecID = cd.RecID
                    WHERE rn > 1
    END


--CASE 2: Update on JOIN to nested SELECT

IF @Method = 2
    BEGIN
        UPDATE OR2
            SET DupeOwner = 0
                FROM @OwnRec2 OR2
                    JOIN (SELECT RecID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                        (PARTITION BY StockID, TradeDate, Owner0 ORDER BY OwnerNum) AS rn
                        FROM @OwnRec2) cd
                        ON OR2.RecID = cd.RecID
                    WHERE rn > 1
    END


--CASE 3: Update on JOIN to temp table

IF @Method = 3
    BEGIN
        ; WITH CullDupe
            AS (
                SELECT RecID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StockID, TradeDate, Owner0 ORDER BY OwnerNum) AS rn
                    FROM @OwnRec2
                )

        INSERT INTO @CullDupe SELECT RecID FROM CullDupe WHERE rn > 1

        UPDATE OR2
            SET DupeOwner = 0
                FROM @OwnRec2 OR2
                    JOIN @CullDupe cd
                        ON OR2.RecID = cd.RecID
    END


--CASE 4: Update using counted loop

IF @Method = 4
    BEGIN
        ; WITH CullDupe
            AS (
                SELECT RecID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StockID, TradeDate, Owner0 ORDER BY OwnerNum) AS rn
                    FROM @OwnRec2
                )

        INSERT INTO @CullDupe SELECT RecID FROM CullDupe WHERE rn > 1
        SET @Counter1 = 0
        WHILE @Counter1 < (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @CullDupe)
            BEGIN
                SET @Counter1 += 1
                UPDATE OR2
                    SET DupeOwner = 0
                        FROM @OwnRec2 OR2
                            WHERE RecID = (SELECT RecID FROM @CullDupe WHERE ID = @Counter1)
            END
    END


--CASE 5: Update using JOIN to CTE, but updating all rows (CASE to identify)

IF @Method = 5
    BEGIN
        ; WITH CullDupe
            AS (
                SELECT RecID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StockID, TradeDate, Owner0 ORDER BY OwnerNum) AS rn
                    FROM @OwnRec2
                )

        UPDATE OR2
            SET DupeOwner = CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                FROM @OwnRec2 OR2
                    JOIN CullDupe cd
                        ON OR2.RecID = cd.RecID
    END

SELECT 'Method ' + CAST(@Method AS NVARCHAR(1)) + ': ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(ms,@StartTime,GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' milliseconds'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue with table variables.

The execution plans for your statements referencing them are compiled before the batch even begins executing and thus before the insert statements have executed.

If you select one in one of your problem execution plans and look in the properties window you will see that the table cardinality is 0.

[image]

It still nonetheless assumes that 1 row will be emitted from the empty table as this is the minimum row estimate in most circumstances from a leaf operator in an execution plan. The sub tree on the inside of the nested loops is executed once for each row from the driving table. As this is estimated to be 1 row the highlighted sub tree below is estimated to be executed once. In fact the whole sub tree will be executed 8,000 times (including the expensive table scan and  sort operators).

[image]

When you materialise the result of the row numbering to a table variable you store the result of that subtree and thus ensure that this is only calculated once (though the plan using it still has a sub optimal nested loops join onto the new table variable).

Common solutions to the one row estimate are to add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to problem statements so that table cardinality at statement execution time can be taken into account, or use trace flag 2453 (which can trigger automatic recompiles after cardinality changes) 
or use a #temp table instead (which can trigger automatic recompiles and additionally benefit from column statistics)

More details about some of this can be found [in my answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server/16386#16386).

Comment: That is absolutely incredible. OPTION(RECOMPILE) took me from 48,136 ms down to 13 ms. Thanks for taking the time to explain this.

Comment: Follow-up. I had another chance to use this today. 18,000 rows, no problem, with all sorts of joins and all sorts of stuff. But the I needed to add on one more piece, and that join took it up over two minutes. Driving me crazy. I tried a CTE, then a table variable, then a temp table. Finally I went back to this post and looked at the code I had created as a result. I ended up creating my original table variable, then doing an update on it using another table variable using OPTION (RECOMPILE). 6 seconds. 6 seconds! I had gotten it down to 55, and that was awesome, comparatively. But now 6! Wow.